# Resilience4j's patterns are not being executed due to CustomExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, circuit-breaker, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I was asked to implement both `@CircuitBreaker` and `@Retry` patterns in a project where a `CustomExceptionHandler` (`@ControllerAdvice`) is used to perform interceptions.

As custom outputs (based on custom models) are being returned instead of default exceptions, none of them are being executed.

Both `@CircuitBreaker` and `@Retry` patterns have some parameters to trigger themselves when specific exceptions occur, but the application is not having exceptions, but custom response entities.

Is there any idea to fix this conflict? Resilience4j's documentation doesn't include anything similar.

Comment: Not even fallbacks are getting executed because of the same issue (not identifying any "desired" exception).

Comment: Did you try to annotate an endpoint with the CB and retry where you don't have a custom exception handler? Does that setup work as expected?